# Split complex text in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, substring

I have a string as below:

6121gog211222   412 5511.0  2011-11-29 01:14:46.63231   623 734 I   A-BB    {"C":true,"A":"KA.NA_CH","T":250,"L":100,"P":false,"LV":"12.0"}

I want to split the string and extract the parts "01:14:46, true, 250, 100 and false".

I tried using strsplit function, but it break the problem into more sub-problems.

Is there an easier way of splitting this text?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use regular expressions to match your substrings. You can read more about regular expressions in MATLAB [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html)

This isn't the prettiest answer but it works. I'm assuming your source string keeps the same format with only one "time" string of format `??:??:??` and data in the format `"label":value` with fields separated by commas. In that case the following should work.

Define a function `getval`:

```
function val=getval(str,label)
%// return the value from the input 'str' associated with the string in 'label'
i1=regexp(str,sprintf('"%s"',label)); %// first index
i2=regexp(str(i1:end),',|}','once'); %// index where field ends
val = str(i1+3+numel(label):i1+i2-2); %// value
```

You can get your answer using this function as follows:

```
str = sprintf('6121gog211222 412 5511.0 2011-11-29 01:14:46.63231 623 734 I A-BB\n{"C":true,"A":"KA.NA_CH","T":250,"L":100,"P":false,"LV":"12.0"}');

ii=regexp(str,'..:..:..');
sprintf('%s, %s, %s, %s and %s', ...
          str(ii:ii+7), ...
          getval(str,'C'), ...
          getval(str,'T'), ...
          getval(str,'L'), ...
          getval(str,'P') )
```

Comment: Yes, the string format will be always the same. Your method is a simple, efficient way of doing it.

Comment: I just cannot understand what are the ',|}' and 'once' terms as regex arguments. What do they do?

Comment: The ',|}' searches for a ',' or a '}', which will mark the end of that field. '|' means "or" in regexp syntax. The '}' will only be matched if the field is the last one in the curly braces so you could also get the 'LV' value if you wanted. The 'once' argument tells the `regexp` function to only return the index of the first string that matches the regular expression.